# iPhone 5s iOS 10 icloud unlock

Tags: ios, apple-id

hi I am an iPhone 5s second hand user. When I update my phone, it is locked and I don't know the original owners icloud ID and password. so it is locked and can not open my phone right now. so please tell me the steps to unlock the icloud . I have search in the Google and YouTube but the answer that shown in that is completely fake. so help me

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible unless the previous owner removes the device from their icloud account.